# POST http://localhost:3001/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, nodemailer

I am having an issue getting a contact form using nodemailer to function in a production environment.  Within development, I am successful sending emails, however in production I receive the following error: "POST http://localhost:3001/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED", and "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch".

Here is a snippet of my code with  my submit function.

````
const submitEmail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log({ formdata });
    let url;
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?  url = `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/send`
            : url = "http://localhost:3001/send";
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ formdata }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(async (res) => {
        const resData = await res;
        console.log(resData);
        if (resData.status === "success") {
          setMessage("Message Sent!");
        } else if (resData.status === "fail") {
          setMessage("Message failed to send");
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        setFormdata({
          name: "",
          email: "",
          subject: "",
          message: "",
        });
      });
  };```

I have attempted to implement the following solutions with no luck:{unsuccessful}
1: Change the url address from localhost, to heroku address.{unsuccessful}
2: Utilize a cors-anywhere proxy (url ="cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/localhost:3001/send"){unsuccessful}
3: Edit the environment variables in heroku {unsuccessful}
4: Change the port number in server.js {unsuccessful}
5: Added Procfile to manually start node and npm server {unsuccessful}
````

Answer (score 0):

```
 let url;
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?  url = `https://.herokuapp.com/send`
            : url = "http://localhost:3001/send";
```

Well, this line in your code says, when NODE_ENV will be 'production' the URL will

**`https://.herokuapp.com/send`**

The above URL doesn't seem to be a valid URL, because Heroku has a subdomain before herokuapp like my-app.herokuapp.com

You can simply do the following to test it on localhost:

```
 let url;
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?  url = `http://localhost:3001/send`
                : url = "http://localhost:3001/send";
```